Using Modelbuilder to Iterate Rasters and Calculate
I have a series of files in a folder:

2020-04-28-00_00_2020-04-28-23_59_Sentinel-2_L1C_B04_(Raw).tiff
2020-04-28-00_00_2020-04-28-23_59_Sentinel-2_L1C_B05_(Raw).tiff
2024-04-27-00_00_2024-04-27-23_59_Sentinel-2_L1C_B04_(Raw).tiff
2024-04-27-00_00_2024-04-27-23_59_Sentinel-2_L1C_B05_(Raw).tiff
and others that follow that format.

I need to calculate (B05-B04)/(B05+B04) for each date and output:

2020-04-28-00_00_2020-04-28-23_59_Sentinel-2_L1C_Composite.tiff
2024-04-27-00_00_2024-04-27-23_59_Sentinel-2_L1C_Composite.tiff

This would be easer in Python but I have to use ModelBuilder.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You'll still need to use Python in a Calculate Value tool to extract out the constant part of the file name if you want to go down the ModelBuilder route.
I think when looping within loops it will be easier if done in Python.  You can write your Python code and embed it into a script tool.  From a user’s perspective it will be no different to a model run as a tool. So if your concerns are to do with usability then your non-power user won't be able to tell the difference!

Thank you! I did not know that you could use Python within Modelbuilder. This is just the solution I needed.

Have a look here for examples.
